# How to display paths/lines when I'm hovering circles instead of Voronoi cells?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, voronoi

I'm searching a solution. I started from this example : http://mbostock.github.io/d3/talk/20111116/airports.html

Here, you can hover the map, and see the lines appearing at same time.

But, lines are appearing even if you aren't on a circle.

I'm actually searching for a solution where lines (or paths) are displaying only when you hover a circle?

That's why I wrote this part of code :

```
var c = circles.selectAll("circle")
        .data(airports)
        .enter().append("svg:circle")
        .attr("cx", function(d, i) { return positions[i][0]; })
        .attr("cy", function(d, i) { return positions[i][1]; })
        .attr("r", function(d) { return d.r })
        .style("fill", function(d){ return d.color})
        .sort(function(a, b) { return countByAirport[b.iata] - countByAirport[a.iata]; });

         c.on("mouseover", function(e){
           g.select("path.arc")
            .style("display", "inherit")
           });
        });
        c.on("mouseout", function(e){
           g.select("path.arc")
            .style("display", "none");
        });
```

I'm probably far away from the good way to do this. Here, with my code, I can display all paths when I'm hovering each circles. I take others solutions too, I can leave Voronoi (as I don't want to use cells, maybe you know another way more practicable...).

My ultimate goal would be to find this answer, and then, to display paths which is/are only concerned by the circle which is hovered. I need more precision compared to Voronoi, but it seemed good at first, for paths i.e.).

I could add more code, but globally, it is the same as the example above

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a solution to your ultimate goal - display paths related to the hovered circle

https://shashank2104.github.io/d3-Voronoi/

**Relevant code changes:**

1. Added a class to the `<g>` containing the arcs

   ```
   .enter().append("svg:g").attr('class', function(d) { return d.iata; });
   ```
2. Changed mouseover and mouseout events for the circles to display the arcs **based**on the class added in the first step.

   ```
   circles.on("mouseover", function(d){
       console.log(d.iata);
      cells.select('g.'+d.iata).selectAll("path.arc")
       .style("display", "inherit")
   }).on("mouseout", function(d){
      cells.select('g.'+d.iata).selectAll("path.arc")
           .style("display", "none");
   });
   ```
3. Took off the CSS that displayed all arcs:

   ```
   #cells g:hover path.arc {
     display: inherit;
   }
   ```

I could add more code but I'm guessing you can look at the source code on the github page.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Glad I could help!